# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical while upgrading liferay DB

Tags: java, liferay

I am upgrading from `liferay dxp 7.0` to `liferay dxp 7.2` while running db-upgrade facing this issue. I am using SQL server as back end. All configuration done by liferay db upgrade blogs.

The logs are:

```
    Starting initial bundles
    java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.internal.activator.ConfigurationPersistenceImplBundleActivator.start() of bundle com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.impl.
    ......
        at com.liferay.portal.tools.db.upgrade.client.DBUpgraderLauncher.main(DBUpgraderLauncher.java:55)
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.internal.activator.ConfigurationPersistenceImplBundleActivator.start() of bundle com.liferay.portal.configuration.persistence.impl.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:800)
        ......
        at com.liferay.portal.util.InitUtil.initWithSpring(InitUtil.java:226)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:418)
        ......
        ... 19 more
```

The complete logs is at https://pastebin.com/ZzLN0qwW

Comment: You seem to have formatted regular text as code an code as text :(

Comment: Can you provide the blogs you used so we know what steps you've tried already?

Comment: Are you creating a File from a URI in your code?  What are the lines that come after `java.io.File.<init>` in the stack trace?

Comment: Hi @dbJones  this is the url :https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028711752-Upgrading-Your-Test-Server-and-Database

Comment: Portal-upgrade-database.properties:

jdbc.default.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:sqlserver://hostname;databaseName=LiferayDev30Jul20
jdbc.default.username=user
jdbc.default.password=pwd

app-server.properties:

dir=M:\Rahul\liferay-dxp-7.2.10.2-sp2\tomcat-9.0.33
extra.lib.dirs=/bin
global.lib.dir=/lib
portal.dir=/webapps/ROOT
server.detector.server.id=tomcat

portal-upgrade-ext.properties

liferay.home=M:/Rahul/liferay-dxp-7.2.10.2-sp2